# Django Model Definition Race

Tags: django

How do you deal with the case where you have a model (A) that relies on model (B) being defined, but model (B) also relies on model(A) being defined.

For instance, I have

```
class event(models.Model):
    competition_start = models.DateField() 
    competitors = models.ManyToManyField(picture)
    results = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=20)

class picture(models.Model):
    uploader = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile)
    upload_date = models.DateField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=10)
    score_RD = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=10)
    rated = models.BooleanField()
    last_competed = models.DateField() 
    competition = models.OneToOneField(event)
```

The competitors field relies on picture being defined but picture relies on event being defined.

Note that each picture (A) shares a one to one relationship with an event, but the event can involve multiple other pictures (set(S)-A).

I tried swapping over to putting

```
competitors = models.ManyToManyField(picture) 
user_pic = models.OneToOneField(picture)
```

inside of event and getting rid of the field 'competition', but I believe SQL does not allow this. Can someone explain why?

What fix should I perform if I need a OneToOne relationship for one field and 
a ManyToMany relationship with another? (between the two same classes)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in the string of the class name to the definition of `OneToOne` and `ForeignKey` and have it evaluated "lazily".

```
competitors = models.ManyToManyField('picture')
```

Also, the convention for model class names is camel-case (e.g. 'picture' => 'Picture', 'event' => 'Event').

Comment: Ahh..thank you so much ; it appears to have fixed the problem. However, can you possibly explain why you can have a field in event that has a OneToOne relationship with picture, and picture can have a field that has a ManyToMany relationship with event. But you can't have two fields in event where one is a ManyToMany relationship with picture and the other is a OneToOne relationship with picture?

Comment: There's no reason you shouldn't be able to do that.  What's the error you're getting when you try it?

Answer (score 1):

```
class event(models.Model):
  competition_start = models.DateField() 
  competitors = models.ManyToManyField('MODULE.picture')
  results = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=20)
  ...
```

Also, by definition you can't have both a one-to-one and a many-to-many.  I think you want the relationship on the Picture class to be a foreignkey not a one-to-one.